# Material-UI Autocomplete Checkboxes question

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI Autocomplete Checkboxes

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes

**How I can disable the keyboard to not appear when Mobile?**

It is very annoying and takes 1/2 of the screen ; my dropdowns are very short

I want something like that but the keyboard...
[image]

thanks

Comment: This appears to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811527/material-ui-autocomplete-disable-keyboard-input-on-mobile

Comment: I test that did not work maybe I miss something